# Can I change the codeigniter inputfield output?

Tags: html, codeigniter, xhtml

I'm developing my website with codeigniter. The doctype is in html 4.01 strict and codeigniter outputs input /> br />. How can I make codeigniter stop outputtig xhtml?

Comment: maybe try and find an old framework that will give you old standard compliant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the form helper... http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change in the system-files. But why would you change?

Comment: Because else the validator says it's not valid html.

Comment: Then start using xHTML or HTML5. It's awesome!